# Is there a way in Python to select only certain variables (from the data set) for input features used in Deep Learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, survival-analysis

I am very new to implementing deep-learning for survival analysis using Pycox package.

I am using The Molecular Taxonomy of Breast Cancer International Consortium (METABRIC), which
contains variables x0 to x8 with time duration and event (0=no, 1=yes).

When I did the example from the Pycox [Pycox Github](https://github.com/havakv/pycox#references), I realized that by default, all the variables
from x0 to x8 are being used as input features for training, testing, and validation

However, I want to train the LogisticHazard (Nnet-survival) including only certain features as follows:

Model 1=x0, x1, x2

Model 2=x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5

Model 3=x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8

[Pycox-LogisticHazard Example with METABRIC](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/havakv/pycox/blob/master/examples/01_introduction.ipynb)

```
df_train = metabric.read_df()

df_test = df_train.sample(frac=0.2)

df_train = df_train.drop(df_test.index)

df_val = df_train.sample(frac=0.2)

df_train = df_train.drop(df_val.index)

df.train.head()
```

[Data Set Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thWRg.png)

How do I easily set Model 1, Model 2, Model 3 for training, testing, and validation sets?
so that I can customize which input variables (e.g Model 1: x0, x1, x2) to use for x_train, x_val, x_test ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As soon as you read the data set, simply delete the slice of columns you don't want for that run.

Comment: Thank you. How would I do this?

Comment: You would enter "PANDAS remove columns" into your browser 's search bar -- especially on Stack Overflow.